# Attempting to clear the values in two cells in a different workbook when I close the workbook. Run-time 91 error

Tags: vba, excel

I'm attempting to clear the values in two cells in a different workbook when I close the workbook I'm actively using.  When I close my workbook I receive the following error:

> Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set

Using debug and stepping through I can find the line where I receive the error but for the life of me I'm not seeing what I'm missing.

I call my macro from:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    TestClear

End Sub

Sub TestClear()

    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.DisplayAlerts = False

    Dim SourceWb As Workbook, myWS As Worksheet

    Set SourceWb = Workbooks.Open("Workbook file location, in this case it's on a network share")
    Set myWS = SourceWb.Sheets("Sheet1") <---- Here is where I receive the Run-Time error    '91'

    myWS.Range("A1").Clear
    myWS.Range("B1").Clear

    SourceWb.Close SaveChanges:=1
    ThisWorkbook.Close SaveChanges:=1

    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: Do you have a Worksheet, named `Sheet1`?

Comment: Yes, I've left Sheet1 in the sourceWB.  Manually opening that workbook confirms Sheet1 exists and the values I'm writing to cells A1 and B1 are there.

Comment: From your code i understand that you are using a macro that will open and excel and then you want to delete something from the excel you just opened. If my assumption it's correct you need to declare the new excel. 
Try something like this :Application.DisplayStatusBar = False
    Dim xl As New Excel.Application
    xl.Workbooks.Open (Worksheets("MAIN").Range("B7").Value)
    xl.Visible = True
    With xl
        Worksheets("something").Range("A1").clear
        Worksheets("something").Range("A1").clear
    End With

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are victim of a re-entrant, theoretically never-ending routine. **Without disabling events**, inside `Workbook_BeforeClose`, you call `ThisWorkbook.Close`  which will again cause `Workbook_BeforeClose` to be invoked, then again and again. This causes **undefined behavior** (probably a *StackOverfow*!)

Quick-fix: disable events:

```
Private Sub Workbook_BeforeClose(Cancel As Boolean)

    Application.EnableEvents = False '<------- To avoid re-entance
    On Error Resume Next
    TestClear
    Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Comment: That was it.  Thank you for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

Try to run the following code until you can do it without an error:

```
Sub TestClear()

    Dim SourceWb        As Workbook
    Dim myWS            As Worksheet

    Set SourceWb = ThisWorkbook
    Set myWS = SourceWb.Worksheets("Sheet1")

    Debug.Print myWS.Name

End Sub
```

Probably the error is in the way you use `SourceWb` or you do not have `Sheet1`.