# vba to copy sheet after saving

Tags: vba, excel

I decided to make a new question because my first wasn't that clear.

I want to copy my sheet to another place after I save the original sheet.

I'm using this code:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)
If Success Then

'Application.DisplayAlerts = False
ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs Filename:="I:\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\01 - Administrativo\06- ADM - Taís e Natalia\04 - Alocados - Equipes\TEC ALOCADOS" & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy"), _
FileFormat:=51
'Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End If
End Sub
```

It sort of works. When I save the file and the `SaveAs` is triggered it seems that it's on a loop.

First it asks me again if I really want to save the new file as a macro-free workbook (which is already true since I've already specified `FileFormat` as 51).

As I click `Yes` it creates the file and then starts a loop where it keeps notifying me that the file already exists and if I want to overwrite it.

If I say yes it continues to ask me.
If I say no then I get:

> Runtime error 1004: Method SaveAs of Object _Workbook failed.

I was trying to insert `Application.DisplayAlerts` to see if it would solve the problem, but it changed nothing, the loop continues and now I just don't get the alerts.

Any suggestions? I really need that the new sheet doesn't have any macros on it.

Comment: Try removing `Filename:=` and just `ActiveWorkbook.SaveAs "I:\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\01 - Administrativo\06- ADM - Taís e Natalia\04 - Alocados - Equipes\TEC ALOCADOS" & " " & Format(Now(), "dd-mm-yyyy"), FileFormat:=51`

Comment: @BruceWayne Same problem... It keeps asking me the same things.

Comment: Try taking a look at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15630035/how-to-clear-the-vba-code-of-a-worksheet-via-a-macro, which removes the code itself, in case this approach might be the way you want to go.

Comment: Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.DeleteLines 1, Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents("ThisWorkbook").CodeModule.CountOfLines should remove the code from your workbook, if using the approach similar to the link.

Comment: I can try this later, but I read the question and actually my code already makes a copy sheet with no code... The problem is just that it shouldn't asks me to rewrite the file or if I want to save a new macro-free or not sheet

Comment: Can you try disabling events in addition to displayAlerts? You might be witnessing a re-entrant event; take a look here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805685/4926357

Comment: The `AfterSave` event will be called after you save the workbook.  If, during the `AfterSave` event, you save the workbook then the `AfterSave` event will fire, which will save the workbook, which will fire the event, which will save the workbook, which will fire the event ....  As @A.S.H says, disable events.

Comment: @A.S.H that solved the problem, thank you!