# Using the Aftersave event

Tags: excel, vba

I have this sheet where I want to make a copy of it everytime you save the original sheet.

To achieve this I was trying to use `AfterSave` on `ThisWorkBook` which calls a macro on a module.

The code is below:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

If Success Then
Application.EnableEvents = False

Call CopiarNovaPlanilha

Application.EnableEvents = True
End If
End Sub
```

The `Application.EnableEvents` is just to avoid a loop as I learnt  [HERE](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44805685/6088173). Here'S the macro inside the module :

```
Sub CopiarNovaPlanilha()

ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "I:\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\ALOCACAO TECNICOS.xlsx"

End Sub
```

This code is working perfectly although the `AfterSave` isn't, so when I save my original file it's not calling my sub as it should.

Anyone knows what is happening with this event?

Comment: Can you clarify, which aspect isn't working? Is the `Workbook_AfterSave` event being called?

Comment: This works for me, although saving the file with xlsx extension will stop it being opened when you get it working. Have you tried running a sub routine to set events on, incase you've disabled them inadvertently whilst writing or debugging?

Comment: I don't know if this would make a difference, but you seem to be saving as a `.xlsx`. Save as a `xlsm` which is macro-enabled.

Comment: @dipper Actually, I need the file to be saved as a `.xlsx` because I don't want macros in my copy.

Comment: @paulinhax fair enough.

Comment: @dipper Also I made an edit on my code in case of `Success` but still doesn't work.

Comment: @wrslphil I already tried without disabling events and got the same problem.

Comment: Sorry, what I mean was, explicitly set them to on in a separate subroutine, to check if they have been left in the off position so to speak. Then run your macro again

Comment: Place a breakpoint at the beginning of the Aftersave Event macro, and then save and press F8 to skip through to see where it's going wrong

Comment: @wrslphil I see... Nothing new, same problem here ):

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this, think it's because you've not tested the condition of the success value. You need to check whether it's true or false

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

If Success = True Then

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    Call CopiarNovaPlanilha

    Application.EnableEvents = True

End If

End Sub
```

Comment: I tested a lot of things, so I really don't know if it was that the problem, but now it's working, so... Thanks :)

Comment: Haha, well at least it works now, that's the main thing. No worries!

Answer (score 2):

I had the issue that the AfterSave event didn't fire and I found out that this **happens only when the visual basic development environment is open**. When I close the VBA editor, the AfterSave event fires as expected.

Comment: You are shear brilliant !! Thanks a million !!!

Answer (score 0):

Calling a sub directly from a workbook event sometimes causes issues. What I would recomend you to try is simply putting the content of your sub into the AfterSave event like so:

```
Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

 Application.EnableEvents = False

 ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "I:\CGP\DEOPEX\01 - Supervisão\10 - Alocação das equipes\Consulta Alocados\ALOCACAO TECNICOS.xlsx"

 Application.EnableEvents = True

End Sub
```

Considering you're not using any variable inside of your sub, I dont see why this wouldn't work!

Comment: I share the same thought just because this was what I was doing before and it wasn't working.

Answer (score 0):

Place the: application.events=false in CopiarNovaPlanilha() instead:

```
  Private Sub Workbook_AfterSave(ByVal Success As Boolean)

Call CopiarNovaPlanilha

End Sub
```

And for the module:

```
Sub CopiarNovaPlanilha()

    Application.EnableEvents = False

    ActiveWorkbook.SaveCopyAs "file location"
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    End Sub
```

Comment: The application.enable events set to False before calling the module is preventing the sub to copy

Comment: The `Application.EnableEvents` is just preventing my `AfterSave` to re-enter and doesn't stop to run. I've tried this solution but it didn't work.

Comment: It is working for me. Some things to check: make sure the file name is correct and has a name at the end. Or else it will be saving to the previous folder as the name of the folder.